# Laravel email is sent instantly instead of being queued

Tags: php, laravel, email, queue

I created the `queue:table` and then ran `php artisan migrate`, created a mail class (`make:mail`) and configured it.

Then I tried to queue an e-mail:

```
Mail::to($receiver)->queue(new WelcomeMail($user));
                       ^
```

I am running this on my local machine, and as soon as that line is executed, instead of queuing, it instantly tries to send the e-mail.

Please note that I have set no Cronjob on my local machine.

Why is this happening? have I done something wrong?

Comment: Look at the `QUEUE_CONNECTION` in your `.env`. If it's set to `sync`, then it will run right away.

Comment: @ChinLeung After setting that to database it works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using `database` as value of `QUEUE_CONNECTION` in your `.env` instead of `sync`.

Comment: Also `config/queue.php` `default` `QUEUE_CONNECTION` is `database`

Comment: I wonder why there is no mention of this QUEUE_CONNECTION value in Laravel documentation... Thanks anyway, this was the case indeed.

Comment: It was already mentioned under Queues.